# Modal component does not render on a custom button component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, components, react-context

I am trying to render a custom and dynamic modal on button clicks. For example, when a "Game" button is clicked, I would like a modal to render with specfics about the game and when a "Bank" button is clicked, I would like the modal to populate with specfics about a bank.

First, when I add an onClick function to a custom button component, the modal does not render. However, when I put the onClick function on a regular button, the modal does render. How can I simply add an onClick function on any component to render a dynamic modal?

Second, I would like to populate each modal with differnet data. For example, a "Game" button would populate the modal with a title of "Game" and so on. I'm using props to do this, but is that the best solution?

Here is the code I have so far, but it is broken when I add the onClick function to components.

```js
// Navbar.js
import { ModalContext } from '../contexts/ModalContext'

function Navbar() {
  const [showModal, updateShowModal] = React.useState(false)
  const toggleModal = () => updateShowModal((state) => !state)

return(
<ModalContext.Provider value={{ showModal, toggleModal }}>
  <Modal
  title="Title"
  canShow={showModal}
  updateModalState={toggleModal}
  />
  </ModalContext.Provider>
 )

  // does not render a modal
  <Button
  onClick={toggleModal}
  type="navItem"
  label="Game"
  icon="windows"
  />

    // render a modal
    <button onClick={toggleModal}>Show Modal</button>
  )
}
```

```js
import { ModalContext } from '../contexts/ModalContext'
// Modal.js
const Modal = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <ModalContext.Consumer>
      {(context) => {
        if (context.showModal) {
          return (
            <div style={modalStyles}>
              <h1>{title}</h1>
              <button onClick={context.toggleModal}>X</button>
            </div>
          )
        }

        return null
      }}
    </ModalContext.Consumer>
  )
}
```

```js
// modalContext.js
export const ModalContext = React.createContext()
```

```js
// Button.js
function Button({ label, type = 'default', icon }) {
  return (
    <ButtonStyle buttonType={type}>
      {setIcon(icon)}
      {label}
    </ButtonStyle>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you share the `Button` component implementation? Does it proxy the `onClick` prop on to any underlying DOMNode/element that is clickable? If you want to make the modal content dynamic then I suggest making that part of the `ModalContext` state and exposing out updater functions for it. I also see that your `ModalContext.Provider` isn't rendering/wrapping `children` so it's not able to actually provide an upstream context to any consumers.

Comment: Check my updated code for the Button.js implementation.

Comment: I see, it doesn't destructure and pass an `onClick` prop to anything, so it's not clickable. Can you also share `ButtonStyle` component?

Comment: @DrewReese ButtonStyle is just styled components within the same Button.js file.
It is just this: `const ButtonStyle = styled.button`....`

Answer (score 1):

## First problem:

I think the `onClick` prop of the `<Button>` component is not pointing to the `onClick` of the actual `HTML button` inside the  component.
Could you please check that? And if you think It's been set up in the right way, then can you share the code of the  component?

## Second Problem

Yes, there's another way to do that. And I think it's [React Composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#composing-components). You can build the modal as the following:

```
<Modal
  showModal={showModal}
  updateModalState={toggleModal}
>
  <div className="modal__header">{title}</div>
  <div className="modal__body">{body}</div>
  <div className="modal__footer">{footer}</div>
</Modal>
```

I think this pattern will give you more control over that component.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You are not passing the `onClick` prop through to the styled button component.

## Solution

Given style-component button:

```
const ButtonStyle = styled.button``;
```

The custom `Button` component needs to pass all button props on to the `ButtonStyle` component.

```
// Button.js
function Button({ label, type='default', icon, onClick }) {
  return (
    <ButtonStyle buttonType={type} onClick={onClick}>
      {setIcon(icon)}
      {label}
    </ButtonStyle>
  )
}
```

If there are other button props then you can use the Spread syntax to collect them into a single object that can then be spread into the `ButtonStyle` component.

```
// Button.js
function Button({ label, type = 'default', icon, ...props }) {
  return (
    <ButtonStyle buttonType={type} {...props}>
      {setIcon(icon)}
      {label}
    </ButtonStyle>
  )
}
```

## Second Question

For the second issue I suggest encapsulating the open/close/title state entirely in the modal context provider, along with the `Modal` component.

Here's an example implementation:

```
const ModalContext = React.createContext({
  openModal: () => {},
});

const Modal = ({ title, onClose}) => (
  <>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <button onClick={onClose}>X</button>
  </>
)

const ModalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState('');

  const openModal = (title) => {
    setShowModal(true);
    setTitle(title);
  }

  const closeModal = () => setShowModal(false);

  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider value={{ openModal }}>
      {children}
      {showModal && <Modal title={title} onClose={closeModal} />}
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Example consumer to set/open a modal:

```
const OpenModalButton = ({ children }) => {
  const { openModal } = useContext(ModalContext);

  return <button onClick={() => openModal(children)}>{children}</button>
}
```

Example usage:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <ModalProvider>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

        <OpenModalButton>Modal A</OpenModalButton>
        <OpenModalButton>Modal B</OpenModalButton>
      </div>
    </ModalProvider>
  );
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit modal-component-does-not-render-on-a-custom-button-component]